# Открытие файла по частям

Tags: android, filestream

Есть файл со строкой в 16МБ. Мне нужно как то открывать его по частям, т.е. в идеале по индексу начало и конца. Типа этого:

```
"моядлиннаястрока".substring(1,3)
```

Возможно ли это реализовать?

Следующий код не подходит мне (колхозно ?):

```
int Size = 4;
is = new FileInputStream(saveFilePath);
isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
br = new BufferedReader(isr);
char[] cbuf = new char[is.available()];
br.read(cbuf, 0, Size);
for (char c:cbuf)
    {
        SmallKeyTemp=SmallKeyTemp+c;
    }
```

Сейчас я делаю так:

```
                 public String LoadFromFile(String FileName, int startPosition, int Count)
    {
        String list = "";
        try {
            String saveFilePath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/" + FileName;

            if (new File(saveFilePath).exists()) {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(saveFilePath));

                int Position = 1;
                int EndPosition = startPosition + Count - 1;

                int symbol = bufferedReader.read();
                while (symbol != -1) {

                    Log.i("MyLogIlnar", "Position " + Position);

                    if (Position >= startPosition && Position <= EndPosition) {
                        list = list + (char) symbol;
                    } else {
                        if (Position > EndPosition) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    Position++;
                    symbol = bufferedReader.read(); // Читаем символ
                }
            }

            Log.i("MyLogIlnar", "Считал вот такие данные "+list);


        } catch (Exception g) {g.printStackTrace();}

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Кодировка строки какая? В смысле, есть ли двухбайтовые символы?

Comment: Да, есть двухбайтовые символы .

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно построчно копировать текст из файла и вставлять его в `StringBuilder`, например так:

```
String saveFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(saveFilePath + "/text.txt"));
StringBuilder totalText = new StringBuilder();
String textLine;
while((textLine= bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    totalText.append(textLine);
}
```

В вашем случае скорей всего подвиснет, и если будет так, то можно этот код выполнить в `AsyncTask`

Comment: Андройд Андройд, как я понимаю у меня в файле одна строка и readLine() считывает сразу все 16мб и вылетает ошибка OUTOFMEMORY